# Error in making DM prompts using discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to make a prompt in DMs, I tried using this and it doesn't work.

```py
@client.command()
async def event(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Prompt will continue in DMs.")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Event Prompt", description="Please specify the type of event.")
    embed.set_footer(text="Prompt will expire in 30 seconds")
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    eventType = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author), timeout=30) # I want it to dm the user and wait for them to respond.
    await ctx.send(eventType) # I want it to send the event type.
```

Here's my error:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'check' is not defined`

Comment: You need to define it, as the error says. The `check` you provided does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

message.Check is a function the discord asks to check for certain conditions. You can make this function before this listener and call it. This will check if its the user is the same and if the channel is the same. Make sure you want to send the msg not the msg object so instead of `await ctx.send(eventType)` type `await ctx.send(eventType.content)`

```py
async def handle(self, params, message, client):
                    def check(m):
                        return m.author.id == message.author.id and m.channel == message.channel
                    
                    msg = "Please enter a username: "
                    await channel.send(msg)
                    log = msg

                    username = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=600.0)
                    username = username.content
                    await message.channel.send(username)
```

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with the commands module because I use a custom template. If you would like to send me your discord I can help you there.

Comment: officer grr#6609